# Rails test error " UNIXServer is required (LoadError)" on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am running into an issue when trying to execute "rails test" on windows.

Issue:

```
 17: from test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        14: from C:/Users/ES0074223/RubyOnRails/firefly/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from C:/Users/ES0074223/RubyOnRails/firefly/test/test_helper.rb:6:in `<class:TestCase>'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:82:in `parallelize'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:82:in `new'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:54:in `initialize'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1710:in `start_service'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1710:in `new'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1404:in `initialize'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:772:in `open_server'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:804:in `auto_load'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:297:in `require'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:263:in `load_dependency'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:297:in `block in require'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:297:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/unix.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': UNIXServer is required (LoadError)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have u tried updating your Rails version? It says it is using the beta1 version of 6.0.0

Comment: problem still exists in rails 6.0.1, see comment below

Answer (score 4):

Might be related to  [Rails Issue  #34410 Windows support for parallelization and instrumenter](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34410)

Problem still exists today (end of nov 2019)

```
$ rails test
Traceback (most recent call last):
    28: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    ...
     8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:58:in `initialize'
     7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1715:in `start_service'
     6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1715:in `new'
     5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1403:in `initialize'
     4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:772:in `open_server'
     3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:804:in `auto_load'
     2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
     1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
     C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/unix.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': UNIXServer is required (LoadError)
```

The important part of the error messages was from **testing/parallelization.rb**.

In test/test_helper.rb: add "with threads":

```
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)
```

But this alone did not solve the problem. I also had
to upgrade sass-rails to version 6 (I had 5 before) in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
```

and do a bundle update.

Why sass-rails is involved is a mystery.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. I _didn't_ have to  do anything more than `with: :threads`

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](http://ruby.11.x6.nabble.com/DRb-error-UNIXServer-is-required-LoadError-td3455876.html), it looks like this issue comes from the application using Unix sockets, which isn't supported on Windows.

I strongly suggest you run the application in Docker. This will solve your issues, but will -- of course -- not be a native windows experience.

Comment: That is one way of avoiding Windows.  Using the Linux Subsystem would be another.  Both are a hurdle to new developers.  Is there still a way to use Ruby and Rails and Windows simply?

Comment: Yeah, I understand this is a suboptimal solution, but it was a solution :)

Comment: If you want it to run natively you need to rewrite whatever part uses Unix sockets within the app.

Comment: no, actually I found a fix without having to rewrite anything. see above

Comment: Nice that you got it solved. One could argue that changing your code from something to something else is a rewrite ;)

Comment: without having to rewrite  whatever part uses Unix sockets within the app